# How Can I Fix My Google Maps App?

Tags: google, maps

Maps worked fine on my Galaxy S5 up until a few days ago. All of a sudden, I can't access my history, get directions or see the map of where I am when I open the app. When I go to the menu, it still lists the email that connects to my account, but nothing works. Still works fine on my other devices. History, directions, etc., show up on my laptop & tablet on the same account. I tried signing out & signing in again and deleting updates. No change.

How can I get my Maps working again?

Comment: If you have a resolution, please write your own answer about what you did to fix it and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to maps in the app settings and delete data, and if that doesn't work you can uninstall updates and update it again to reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I have done everything that you mentioned and the problem still persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Ira Is sync on? If not that might be the problem.

Comment: Hi Grant, yes, sync is on, and as I said, "Maps worked fine on my Galaxy S5 up until a few days ago. All of a sudden, I can't access my history, get directions or see the map of where I am when I open the app". I hadn't changed anything (like turning off sync or anything else) and it just stopped working.

Comment: Yesterday I got a typical notification that 7 apps have updates available (I always keep them updated, including Google Maps), Google, Google+, Google Maps, and other assorted apps. I updated all. My Google Maps came back! Works perfectly now.